# Lock-free stack: visibility issue when checking hazard pointers during pop()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lock-free, memory-barriers

I'm reading Anthony William's *C++ Concurrency in Action*. Chapter 7 describes the process of developing a lock-free stack and illustrates common issues that make lock-free programming difficult. Specifically, section 7.2.3 (*Detecting nodes that can't be reclaimed using hazard pointers*) describes how hazard pointers can be used to avoid a data race and make sure other threads don't `delete` a node still referenced by another thread.

This code is one of the iterations of `pop()` illustrated in that chapter:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
{
  std::atomic<void*>& hp = get_hazard_pointer_for_current_thread();
  node* old_head = head.load();

  do
  {
    node* temp;

    do
    {
      temp = old_head;
      hp.store(old_head);
      old_head = head.load();
    } while(old_head != temp);
  }
  while(old_head &&
    !head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head,old_head->next));

  hp.store(nullptr);
  std::shared_ptr<T> res;

  if(old_head)
  {
    res.swap(old_head->data);

    if(outstanding_hazard_pointers_for(old_head))
    {
      reclaim_later(old_head);
    }
    else
    {
      delete old_head;
    }

    delete_nodes_with_no_hazards();
  }

  return res;
}
```

I have a doubt about this fragment:

```
    if(outstanding_hazard_pointers_for(old_head))
    {
      reclaim_later(old_head);
    }
    else
    {
      delete old_head;
    }
```

The purpose of the hazard pointers is making sure `old_head` is deleted when no other threads may still be using it.  The suggested implementation of `outstanding_hazard_pointers_for` is the following:

```
unsigned const max_hazard_pointers=100;
struct hazard_pointer
{
  std::atomic<std::thread::id> id;
  std::atomic<void*> pointer;
};
hazard_pointer hazard_pointers[max_hazard_pointers];

bool outstanding_hazard_pointers_for(void* p)
{
  for(unsigned i=0; i < max_hazard_pointers; ++i)
  {
    if(hazard_pointers[i].pointer.load() == p)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Basically, the array of hazard pointers is scanned to check whether the pointer to the node looked for is present. I'm wondering why this operation is indeed safe. An atomic `load()` is performed and even if sequentially consistent ordering is used, `load()` may load a stale value.  As a consequence, `p` may not be found, and `pop()` would be deleting a node that is still in use.

Imagine the following happens:

- Thread A starts to execute `pop()` and is preempted *just* before executing:

  ```
  while(old_head &&
    !head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head,old_head->next));
  ```

  Thread A thus sees the current head as `old_head`, which is saved into its hazard pointer. `old_head` will be dereferenced when the thread wakes up and tries to pop the head invoking `head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head, old_head->next)`.
- Thread B starts invoking `pop()` down to

  ```
  if(outstanding_hazard_pointers_for(old_head))
  ```

  `old_head` will be the current head of the stack, that is the same node that thread A is referencing as `old_head`. Thread B will *not* `delete old_head` iff a `load()` on Thread A's hazard pointer returns the latest value stored by Thread A.

Basically: I'm wondering whether Thread B can `load()` a stale value instead of the latest one. Said another way, I'm not sure why it *has* to return the value set by Thread A's (`old_node`).

Where's the flaw in this reasoning?  I cannot find a justification as to why `hp.store(old_head)` on another thread will happen-before `hazard_pointers[i].pointer.load()`.

Comment: I am reading the book and have the exact same question as you. I currently do not understand how the answer below answers your concern. Since you had the same understanding problem, could you rephrase the reason why the scenario you describe cannot happen and we have a "happen before" between the hazard ptr list scan and the store before the CAS?

Comment: JJ15k, I just answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question for two reasons: I think the answer I accepted is not very clear, and [JJ15k's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292524/lock-free-stack-visibility-issue-when-checking-hazard-pointers-during-pop#comment75037391_41292524) confirms that impression.

Basically the key is observing that for another thread to make it through `if(outstanding_hazard_pointers_for(old_head))` *and* seeing the same `old_head` seen by another thread that was preempted before executing `while(old_head && !head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head, old_head->next))`, it has to have executed `head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head, old_head->next)` with the same `old_head`.  But then (assuming `<` indicates a happens-before relationship):

```
thread A: hp.store(old_head)     < 
thread A: old_head = head.load() < 
thread B: head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head, old_head->next)
```

Remember that thread B is seeing the *same* `old_head` we loaded in the first instruction and it's swapping it's value to `old_head->next`. We still see the same value in `head.load()`, that's why it Thread A `hp.store(old_head)` happens-before the Thread B `compare_exchange_strong`.

So the thread that is about to check whether the head contained in the hazard pointer can be deleted *has* to see `old_head`.  Also notice the fundamental role played by `old_head = head.load()` (and the loop that contains those statements that may seem redundant at first sight). Without that `load` operation, there would be no happens-before relationship between the `store` of `old_head` into `hp` and the `compare_exchange_strong`.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: First thanks for taking the time! I am trying to think about it but :What forces the second happen before relationship though? I see no release write from A being read in B. I think I can kind of understand it at the cache coherency level since the XCH will invalidate all copies but I still can't convince myself using the C++ memory model.

Comment: You shouldn't look for acquire-release semantics in that code: all atomic operations are using the sequentially consistent memory order.

Comment: Yes that's what I am exploring , reasoning related to the global total order on the memory location. I have been very busy and haven't given it the thought it requires. Will do that in the next few days

Comment: Got it, my confusion stemmed from not realising one fact : In the sequentially consistent model, for every two operation A and B, either A happens before B , or B happens before A. This is in contrast to release/acquire where the condition is either B acquire happens after release A , or you just don't know. Again many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the code is the following.

If `hp.store(old_head)` in another thread NOT happen-before the call `hazard_pointers[i].pointer.load()` in this thread, it means that this thread successfully performed `head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head,old_head->next)` call. It means that for another thread `old_head != temp`, so it will perform another attempt to store a proper `old_head` as a thread's `hp`.

And it means that the original `old_head` pointer in the current thread can be safely deleted, since it's not actually used by another thread.

Comment: Thanks @art. I've updated the question with an example. Basically, a thread could be preempted _after_ having checked that `old_head == temp`. Another thread could proceed until checking whether the node could be deleted. In that case it is critical that the first thread's `store()` be visible in the second thread's `load()`. I'm wrongly assuming that sequentially consistent loads can read stale values if they do not violate the sequential consistency?

Comment: You significantly modified your original question. Your understanding about reading stale values is correct. But there is no problem in the scenario you described in the modified question neither. Thread B will add `old_head` into reclaim_later list. So that the thread A (or any other thread later) will be able to delete this unused node during `delete_nodes_with_no_hazards` call.

Comment: Sorry if I reiterate, but that's the core of the question: thread B will add `old_head` into the reclaim list iff `outstanding_hazard_pointers_for` returns `true`. When I say "reading a stale value", I mean `outstanding_hazard_pointers_for` _not_ finding `old_head` into the hazard pointers array (e.g.: because the effect of the `store()` aren't visible yet), in which case `outstanding_hazard_pointers_for` would return `false` and `pop()` would `delete` the node.

Comment: The thread's `hp` modified before `while(old_head &&
    !head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head,old_head->next));` condition.   So if you observe in thread B new `head` value from the thread A, you observer also the correct value of A's `hp`. You cannot see the stale version of A's `hp` and the recent version of `head` modified in A.